# average from same rows in one columns

Tags: awk, merge, average, median

I would like to create awk code, which could find same number in $4th column for all rows and count median and average for $4,$5 column and merge it to one row.

INPUT:

```
     chr10  89623184    89624315    1   0.2062732989
     chr10  89623184    89624315    1   0.2155829606
     chr10  89623184    89624315    1   0.2471277767
     chr10  89623184    89624315    2   0.2236894639
     chr10  89623184    89624315    2   0.2291949506
     chr10  89623184    89624315    2   0.2252482173
```

OUTPUT:

> ```
>                              MEAN   MEDIAN         MEAN
>
> chr10 89623184    89624315    1   0.2155829606  0.2229946787 
> chr10 89623184    89624315    2   0.2252482173  0.2260442106
> ```

thank you for help.

Comment: If the `>` characters are not part of your input, remove them (it's enough to simply indent each line by four spaces to format as code/data).

Comment: This is just a set of requirements. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: The biggest problem for me, how could  I compare and merge rows by $4th column in awk..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
  awk '{
    k = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4
    s[k] += $5
    v[k] = k in v ? v[k] FS $5 : $5
  }        
  END {
    for(i=1;i<=length(k);i++) printf "%s"," "
    printf " %s       %s\n","MEDIAN","MEAN"
    for (k in s) {
      n = split(v[k], m, FS)
      asort(m)
      median = n%2==0 ? (m[n/2]+m[n/2+1])/2 : m[(n-1)/2]
      print k, median, s[k]/n
    }
  }' file


                          MEDIAN       MEAN
chr10 89623184 89624315 1 0.2062732989 0.222995
chr10 89623184 89624315 2 0.2236894639 0.226044
```

your key needs to be the first four fields, not just 4.  For median calculation if there are even number of observations computes the average of mid two.

Comment: Ohh, thank you, this code looks really hard. Thanks a lot

Comment: half is calculating the median and printing headers.

Comment: I found a problem with median counting. At first you have to sort it and after that choose middle value. But still time it is great help from you and I you help me so much. thank you again.

Comment: that's what it's supposed to do but perhaps I messed up even/odd number of values.